# Sum $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (k^2+1)\cdot k!$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, factorial

I could not compute the sum of the following series-

---

$$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n (k^2+1)\cdot k!$$

Please tell me how to proceed in the above question.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have tried to rearrange (k2+1) term somehow to reduce the equation but thats not working.Moreover,expandng seems to be of no help to me.Thus ,I didn't show any working as all those attempts failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer will be -
**n.(n+1)!**
Use Mathematical Induction.

Comment: This isn't true for $n=1$.

Comment: I wrote 2 instead of 1.It was a typo.Apologies.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:**

$$(k^2 + 1)k! = (k+2)! - 3(k+1)! + 2k!$$

Comment: How did yo get that term?Please Explain.

Comment: $k^2 + 1 = (k+2)(k+1) - 3(k+1) + 2$.

Answer (score 2):

It can be proven by induction that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n (k^2+1)k! = n(n+1)!$$
This clearly holds for $n=1$. Not suppose it holds for $n$. Then
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(k^2+1)k! = ((n+1)^2+1)(n+1)!+\sum_{k=1}^{n}(k^2+1)k!$$
$$=((n+1)^2+1)(n+1)! + n(n+1)!$$
$$= (n^2+3n+2)(n+1)! = (n+1)(n+2)(n+1)! = (n+1)(n+2)!$$
Thus completing the proof.