# series question

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n (k^2+1)\cdot k!$$

My attempt:

I tried to write it as $(k+1)^2-2k $but it didn't work out because of the 2 in -2k.

What else ehould I do?

Comment: What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: @zkutch basically i want to simplify it such that terms are cancelled out and a final term is remaining

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (k^2+1)\cdot k!$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2287810/sum-sum-limits-k-1n-k21-cdot-k) – found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5En%20(k%5E2%2B1)%5Ccdot%20k!%24)

Comment: I don't want a method using induction

Comment: @HarshitaJain: Did you read *all* answers to the linded question? There is one using telescoping sums.

Comment: Also this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3521662/series-prove-using-combinational-argument?noredirect=1

Comment: @MartinR yeah i saw it but I didn't understand how to proceed further in that